# jQuery Fancy Transitions with Jquery Tools overlay?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use two tools together. The problem is, that the window won't adjust to different proportions of the images.

Example here: http://axol.de/Axol/HTML/Projects.html

I'm using the Jquery Tools overlay(http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/)

with Jquery Fancy transitions

so I can have multiple pictures in a single overlay. Now I want to have the effect, that when you click on "next image" the box will change its size, if the new image is bigger than the previous one. So I want to adjust the window everytime there is a different sized document. Anyone has an idea how I can apply this? 
I'm fearing that this might result in changing the hole overlay.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the docs, I don't see a way to do what you want. However there are dozens of alternatives that do accomplish what you're looking for and more. Here are a few:

- [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)
- [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
- [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

If you prefer a jQuery plugin to a standalone library, there are six pages worth of options (at the time of this writing) available on [jQuery's plugin site](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/lightbox/).

Comment: Hey, wow thanks :-) I guess I'm gonna delete the old stuff then :-). Thanks for your help! Have a nice day